# Is HTML5Shiv only for Internet Explorer

Tags: html, xhtml, html5shiv

I am new to Web Development. I am currently looking at HTML 5 and I was wondering if HTML5Shiv is only for old Internet Explorers or it also works for other old Browsers of Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 2):

If you so much as bothered to glance at [their project page](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv), the answer would be right in front of you.

> The HTML5 Shiv enables use of HTML5 sectioning elements in legacy
>   Internet Explorer and provides basic HTML5 styling for Internet
>   Explorer 6-9, Safari 4.x (and iPhone 3.x), and Firefox 3.x.

Comment: I had almost the exact same response (but you beat me to the punch)